# Numpy add one column to other columns and remove

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Say I have an 2d numpy array like this

```
[[1,2,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9]]
```

I then want to convert it to

```
[[3,4],
 [9,10],
 [15,16]]
```

This could be a variable number of columns, I want to add the first column to every other column and remove it as well afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = a[..., [0]] + a[..., 1:]
```

The ...is for this to work with N dimensional arrays

Means -> Sum the [0] column to all the columns after the first one.

If you are using just a matrix you can use:

```
a = a[:, [0]] + a[:, 1:]
```

Comment: I was not aware of the "..." notation. Is this functionally the same as say slice but less notationally confusing? In terms of say runtime efficiency.

Comment: Let's say that you have 4 dimensions in you want to modify just the values in the last one.

Instead of writing a[:, :, :, [0]] *= 2, you can just use the ellipsis operator that will select all the dimensions except the last one. I guess it's a little more expensive as it has to resolve how many dimensions it has to select, but id does not increases the cost of the operation. 

 You can also use it with the initial dimensions of the ndarray (a[[0], [3:5], ...])